# Converting a Gaussian to its quadratic form

Tags: mathematical-statistics, linear-model, gaussian-process

I am reading [A Unifying Review of Linear Gaussian Models](https://cs.nyu.edu/%7Eroweis/papers/NC110201.pdf) and trying to derive the equations there.

**Premise**

$
\begin{align}
x_{t+1}&=Ax_t+w_t \qquad & w_•\sim \mathcal{N}(0,Q)\\
y_{t}&=Cx_t+v_t \qquad & v_•\sim \mathcal{N}(0,R)
\end{align}
$

Now I get that
$
P(x_{t+1}|x_t)=\mathcal{N}(Ax_t,Q)
$
and $ P(y_{t}|x_t)=\mathcal{N}(Cx_t,R)$

If we assume independence between $x_t$ and $x_{t+1}$, the probability of a sequence from 1 to $\tau$ is
$P(x_1,...,x_\tau,{y_1...y_\tau})=P(x_1)\prod_{t=1}^{\tau-1} P(x_{t+1}|x_t)\prod^τ_{t=1}P(y_t|x_t)$

**Question 1**

I don't get how they derive the negative log here, they says it is quadratic form of the matrix

$\log P(y_1,...,y_\tau)=\sum_{t=1}^\tau [(y_t−Cx_t)^TR^{−1}(y_t−Cx_t)+\log|R|]$

I think it equals to

$\log P(y_1,...,y_\tau)=\sum_{t=1}^\tau [v_t^TR^{−1}v_t+\log|R|]$

but cannot work further. I looked at quadratic form of covariance matrix in Wikipedia, but seems not relevant.

Comment: I couldn't follow where you didn't understand. The first one after "Question 1", or the second one?

Comment: Yes, I mean the first equation after Question 1, how do they get that.